# Get HBITMAPs For *ALL* Sizes and Depths of a File Type Icon (C++)

Tags: c++, winapi, icons, type-conversion

**Compiler:** MinGW/GCC

I'm trying to get the HICON of a file type based on what icon windows has registered for that file type, and then grab all of the HICON's images.

The problem is, I can't seem to get anything other than the 32x32 or 16x16 icon. Also, I've looked at `GetIconInfoEx()` but that function doesn't allow me to choose the icon size that I'm wanting, it just sort of arbitrarily pukes up whatever Windows feels like handing me at the time.

I want to *at least* have all of the 16x16, 32x32, and 48x48 icons, but I would really enjoy being able to extract *every* size that's in the HICON that I pass in.

Here's the code I'm currently working with (copy and pasted most of this from the web and stitched it together):

```
HBITMAP GetFileTypeIcon(const char* ext, int type, int depth)
{
    HICON hIcon;
    SHFILEINFO sfi= {0};
    UINT flag = SHGFI_ICON|SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES;
    int wh = 16;
    switch(type)
    {
        default:
        case FILE_ICON_SIZE_16:
        {
            wh = 16; flag|=SHGFI_SMALLICON;
        }
        break;
        case FILE_ICON_SIZE_32:
        {
            wh = 32; flag|=SHGFI_LARGEICON; 
        }
        break;
        case FILE_ICON_SIZE_48:
        {
            wh = 48; flag|=SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX;
        }
        break;
        case FILE_ICON_SIZE_256:
        {
            wh = 256; flag|=SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX;
        }
        break;
    }
    HRESULT hr = SHGetFileInfo(ext,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,&sfi,sizeof(sfi),flag);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        if((type == FILE_ICON_SIZE_48) || (type == FILE_ICON_SIZE_256))
        {
            // THIS PART DOESN'T COMPILE: undeclared function/indentifiers

            // HIMAGELIST* imageList;
            // hr = SHGetImageList(((type == FILE_ICON_SIZE_256)?SHIL_JUMBO:SHIL_EXTRALARGE), IID_IImageList, (void**)&imageList);
            // if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            // {
            //     //Get the icon we need from the list. Note that the HIMAGELIST we retrieved
            //     //earlier needs to be casted to the IImageList interface before use.
            //     hr = ((IImageList*)imageList)->GetIcon(sfi.iIcon, ILD_TRANSPARENT, &hIcon);
            // }
        }
        else
        {
            hIcon=sfi.hIcon;
        }
    }

    // Convert to an HBITMAP (to get it out of the icon...)
    HDC hDC = GetDC(NULL);
    HDC hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
    HBITMAP hMemBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, wh, wh);
    HGDIOBJ hOrgBMP = SelectObject(hMemDC, hMemBmp);

    DrawIconEx(hMemDC, 0, 0, hIcon, wh, wh, 0, NULL, DI_NORMAL);

    SelectObject(hMemDC, hOrgBMP);
    DeleteDC(hMemDC);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hDC);
    DestroyIcon(hIcon);

    return hMemBmp;
}
```

I don't even know what to do about color depths. I'll hazard a guess: make a DC that has a certain color depth (rather than just a compatible DC) and pass that into `DrawIconEx()`?

### *Edit:* I answered my own question after much research/work.

**See my answer below for a way to find and parse the raw icon data.**

Comment: Can you get to the registered icon as a "resource"?   If so, you can iterate on the icon data directly and pull out the sizes/bitdepths you want.

Comment: [This might be useful.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12429114/292432)

Comment: @arx: I can't use `SHGetImageList`, `HIMAGELIST`, etc. because **they aren't declared in `shellapi.h` at all.** I'm *not* using MFC if that is some sort of MFC nonsense. Is it an MFC interface? I couldn't find any conclusive evidence online. SHGetImageList appears to be listed in MSDN as a shell function. I've never used MFC before so I wouldn't know. Also, `commoncontrols.h` apparently doesn't exist in my install.

@Corey: How? A quick google suggests that ExtractIconEx won't get me what I want either (only 16x and 32x icons).

Comment: @Corey: Ah, silly me. Do you mean reading the raw *file data* inside the DLL, exe, or whatever? I can try doing that. (I won't be able to try it for a few hours though, I have other things to do...)

Comment: `HIMAGELIST` is declared in `commoncontrols.h`; `SHGetImageList` in `shellapi.h`.  You can find up-to-date versions on line, [for example](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/browser/trunk/mingw-w64-headers/include/shellapi.h?rev=4249).  And you'll need matching lib files.  Reading the raw data directly from an EXE is possible but tedious; you're better off using `LoadImage` or using the resource functions to go straight to the raw icon data.  The hard bit is determining which file to look in.

Comment: By the time you ask for `SHGFI_ICON` it's too late. An icon represents only a single size/image. You want the icon directory. For that, ask for the icon location, then go parse the icon directory from that location.

Comment: @Raymond Thanks! Now I see what I have to do. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997538.aspx) MSDN article is quite clear on the data structures involved. I'll report back once I get a chance to try it out.

Comment: @Raymond I've just begun coding it, and I have a strange problem. The szDisplayName member of the SHFILEINFO isn't getting filled even though I specify `SHGFI_ICONLOCATION | SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES`. I tried `.txt` and `.pdf`, both of which are on my system - they give back an empty string. I get back icon index of 3 for both (that's weird). But, `SHGFI_TYPENAME` does return the proper description string. What's going on?

Comment: I've finally found [something](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/11186) which suggests this odd behavior is a windows bug. It apparently even happens in Vista (and quite possibly 7)?

Comment: Even supplying the name of a *file* that exists doesn't work (but putting in "c:\\" does?!). It seems one must dig the information out of the registry. Ugh. Going to go try that, hopefully I end up with a working routine after this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I basically had to do everything myself (with the help of the web, Stack Overflow, and several MSDN articles) so I think I'll just post my own solution here.

I ended up parsing the registry to find the locations of the icons of each previously registered file extension, since the API functions that should have easily gotten me the information I wanted have some... problems.

After that I spent several days manually observing the data formats at hand by observing output of an icon program, and with this information in hand I was able to construct an image loader.

I used Allegro game library to make dealing with BITMAP images easier - Win32/GDI is a bit too much to deal with and would have made the code exorbitantly messy.

---

### Finding the Icon Location and Index:

**(1)** Look for extension under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, eg `HKCR\.foo\(default) = "foofile"`

**(2)** Default data of this is the next key to look at, eg `HKCR\foofile\`

**(3)** Default data here is the description eg `HKCR\foofile\(default) = "Foo Document"`

**(4)** The icon location may be in one of two places that I know of:

Either in `HKCR\foofile\DefaultIcon\(default)` **or** there may be an entry something like `HKCR\foofile\CurVer\(default) = "foofile.1"` which tells you to look at the key `HKCR\foofile.1\DefaultIcon\(default)` for the icon location.

***Parsing the Icon Location String:***

The string is simply a path followed by a comma, white space, possibly a negative sign, and a number indicating the "index" of the icon.

***Here's the big gotcha:*** Let the icon index be N. If N is negative (might want to check for negative zeros!), it is a *resource ID* within the file specified. If N is positive, it means to find the **N**'th icon within the file, but the icon is *not necessarily* at resource ID number N.

---

### Parsing Icon Structures Manually:

This is the bulk of the code and time spent, but it works beautifully. First off, here's the data formats for the various sections of color and mask data.

**Data Block Formats:**

```
32bit ... Color Data:
====================================================================================
Little Endian 4 byte ARGB values.
The rows are stored in reverse order (bottom to top).


24bit ... Color Data:
====================================================================================
Little Endian 3 byte RGB values.
Tightly Packed (NO PADDING).
INSERT PADDING BYTES TO GO UP TO NEXT DWORD AT END OF ROW. SET THEM TO 0x00.
The rows are stored in reverse order (bottom to top).


16bit ... Color Data:
====================================================================================
Little Endian 2 byte RGB values. 5 bits each with MSB = 0.
Tightly Packed (NO PADDING).
INSERT PADDING BYTES TO GO UP TO NEXT DWORD AT END OF ROW. SET THEM TO 0x00.
The rows are stored in reverse order (bottom to top).


8bit ... Palette & Color Data:
====================================================================================
The Palette is Little Endian 4 byte RGB0 values. No alpha.
There *might* be up to 256 palette entries.
If number of colors is reported as zero, assume 256 color entires.
The Pixels are 1 byte index values.
INSERT PADDING BYTES TO GO UP TO NEXT DWORD AT END OF ROW. SET THEM TO 0x00.
The rows are stored in reverse order (bottom to top).


4bit ... Palette & Color Data:
====================================================================================
The Palette is Little Endian 4 byte RGB0 values. No alpha.
There *might* be up to 16 palette entries.
If number of colors is reported as zero, assume 16 color entires.
The Pixels are nybble-length index values.
INSERT PADDING BYTES TO GO UP TO NEXT DWORD AT END OF ROW. SET THEM TO 0x00.
The rows are stored in reverse order (bottom to top).


Mask Data:
====================================================================================
Is a string of bytes with mask bits starting at MSB and going towards LSB.
There are ((imagewidth+31)>>5) DWORDS per row in *BIG ENDIAN* order.
Like the color data, there is a set of DWORDS for each row.
The rows are stored in reverse order (bottom to top).
Set unused padding bits/pixels at end of each row to 1. 
0 indicates opaque and 1 indicates transparent.


1bit ... XOR Mask, AND Mask, & Color Data:
====================================================================================
The Palette is Little Endian 4 byte RGB0 values. No alpha.
There should be exactly 2 palette entries: usually 0x00000000 and 0x00FFFFFF.
The two masks follow the Mask Data format decribed above.
The following results from combining two mask bits:
    XOR AND RESULT:
     0   0  Color #0 (Black)
     0   1  Transparent
     1   0  Color #1 (White)
     1   1  Invert Destination Bitmap
```

Of course I wouldn't have left it at this. There's code to be had!

The following code will load up and convert all of the icon images for a given icon location to a vector of 32bpp BITMAPs. If loading a given image fails, it will simply just not be added to the vector (or, in the case of a corrupt icon, it will most likely generate a corrupted image, so be careful).

The code does not support the "invert" color in monochrome images, and will just generate a different color that still has zero alpha.

WARNING: Some psuedo-code is included to shorten things to just the essentials.

### Icon Loader Code (Supports: EXE, DLL, 32bit ICL, ICO):

```
// Code written by Simion32.
// Please feel free to use it anywhere. 
// Credit would be nice but isn't required.

#include "include.h" //std::vectors and whatever else you need
#include <allegro.h>
#include <winalleg.h> //Allegro and Win32
#include "Shellapi.h"

// In the following block, the (required!!) pragmas
// force correct data alignment. Needed in at least GCC.
#pragma pack( push, 1 ) 
typedef struct
{
    BYTE                bWidth;         // Width, in pixels, of the image
    BYTE                bHeight;        // Height, in pixels, of the image
    BYTE                bColorCount;    // Number of colors in image (0 if >=8bpp)
    BYTE                bReserved;      // Reserved ( must be 0)
    WORD                wPlanes;        // Color Planes
    WORD                wBitCount;      // Bits per pixel
    DWORD               dwBytesInRes;   // How many bytes in this resource?
    DWORD               dwImageOffset;  // Where in the file is this image?
} ICONDIRENTRY, *LPICONDIRENTRY;
typedef struct
{
    WORD                idReserved;     // Reserved (must be 0)
    WORD                idType;         // Resource Type (1 for icons)
    WORD                idCount;        // How many images?
    ICONDIRENTRY        idEntries[1];   // An entry for each image (idCount of 'em)
} ICONDIR, *LPICONDIR;
typedef struct
{
   BITMAPINFOHEADER     icHeader;       // DIB header
   RGBQUAD              icColors[1];    // Color table
   BYTE                 icXOR[1];       // DIB bits for XOR mask
   BYTE                 icAND[1];       // DIB bits for AND mask
} ICONIMAGE, *LPICONIMAGE;
#pragma pack( pop)
#pragma pack( push, 2 )
typedef struct
{
   BYTE                 bWidth;         // Width, in pixels, of the image
   BYTE                 bHeight;        // Height, in pixels, of the image
   BYTE                 bColorCount;    // Number of colors in image (0 if >=8bpp)
   BYTE                 bReserved;      // Reserved
   WORD                 wPlanes;        // Color Planes
   WORD                 wBitCount;      // Bits per pixel
   DWORD                dwBytesInRes;   // total size of the RT_ICON resource referenced by the nID member.
   WORD                 nID;            // resourceID of RT_ICON (LockResource to obtain a pointer to its ICONIMAGE)
} GRPICONDIRENTRY, *LPGRPICONDIRENTRY;
typedef struct 
{
   WORD                 idReserved;     // Reserved (must be 0)
   WORD                 idType;         // Resource type (1 for icons)
   WORD                 idCount;        // How many images?
   GRPICONDIRENTRY      idEntries[1];   // The entries for each image
} GRPICONDIR, *LPGRPICONDIR;
#pragma pack( pop )




uint32_t Convert16BitToARGB(uint16_t value)
{
    return (0xFF000000|((value >>  7) & 0x0000F8)|((value <<  6) & 0x00F800)|((value << 19) & 0xF80000));
}
uint32_t GetMaskBit(uint8_t* data, int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
    uint32_t mask_data_rowsize = (((w+31)>>5) * 4);
    return ((~(data[(mask_data_rowsize * ((h-1)-y)) + (x >> 3)] >> (0x07 - (x & 0x07))) & 1) * 0xFFFFFFFF);
}
uint32_t GetColorMonochrome(uint8_t* xordata, uint8_t* anddata, int x, int y, int w, int h, uint32_t* pal)
{
    uint32_t mask_data_rowsize = (((w+31)>>5) * 4);
    uint32_t xor_bit = (((xordata[(mask_data_rowsize * ((h-1)-y)) + (x >> 3)] >> (0x07 - (x & 0x07))) << 1) & 2);
    uint32_t and_bit = (((anddata[(mask_data_rowsize * ((h-1)-y)) + (x >> 3)] >> (0x07 - (x & 0x07)))     ) & 1);
    uint32_t value = (xor_bit | and_bit);
    return pal[value];
}



BITMAP* CreateBmp32bppFromIconResData(void* data, int size, int depth, int w, int h, int colors)
{
    char* pngheader = "\211PNG\r\n\032\n";
    char* cpd = (char*)data;
    bool is_png = ((cpd[0]==pngheader[0])
                && (cpd[1]==pngheader[1])
                && (cpd[2]==pngheader[2])
                && (cpd[3]==pngheader[3])
                && (cpd[4]==pngheader[4])
                && (cpd[5]==pngheader[5])
                && (cpd[6]==pngheader[6])
                && (cpd[7]==pngheader[7]));
    if(is_png)
    {
        //###########################################################
        //#  PSEUDO-CODE: Somehow convert the PNG file into a bitmap.
        BITMAP* result = ConvertPngFileToBmp32bpp(data, size);
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        uint32_t ignore_size = ((BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(data))->biSize;
        BITMAP* bmp = create_bitmap_ex(32,w,h);
        uint32_t pixel_count = (w * h);
        uint32_t color_data_size = ((((((w * depth)+7) >> 3) +3) & ~3) * h);
        switch(depth)
        {
            default: return bmp; break;
            case 32:
            {
                uint32_t* src = (uint32_t*)(((uint8_t*)data) + ignore_size);
                for(int yy = h-1; yy >= 0; --yy){
                    for(int xx = 0; xx < w; ++xx){
                        _putpixel32(bmp,xx,yy,src[0]);
                        src++;
                    }
                    //There should never be any padding to jump over here.
                }
                return bmp;
            }
            break;
            case 24:
            {
                uint32_t* src = (uint32_t*)(((uint8_t*)data) + ignore_size);
                uint8_t* bitmask = (uint8_t*)(((uint8_t*)data) + ignore_size + color_data_size);
                int padding_checker = 0;
                for(int yy = h-1; yy >= 0; --yy){
                    for(int xx = 0; xx < w; ++xx){
                        _putpixel32(bmp,xx,yy,((src[0] & 0x00FFFFFF) | 0xFF000000) & GetMaskBit(bitmask, xx, yy, w, h));
                        src++;
                        src = (uint32_t*)(((uint8_t*)src)-1); //go back a byte due to packing
                        padding_checker += 3;
                        padding_checker &= 3;
                    }
                    //This loop jumps over any padding bytes.
                    while(padding_checker)
                    {
                        src = (uint32_t*)(((uint8_t*)src)+1);
                        padding_checker++;
                        padding_checker &= 3;
                    }
                }
                return bmp;
            }
            break;
            case 16:
            {
                //Note: there might be a color table present! ignore it.
                uint16_t* src = (uint16_t*)(((uint8_t*)data) + ignore_size + (colors << 2));
                uint8_t* bitmask = (uint8_t*)(((uint8_t*)data) + ignore_size + (colors << 2) + color_data_size);
                int padding_checker = 0;
                for(int yy = h-1; yy >= 0; --yy){
                    for(int xx = 0; xx < w; ++xx){
                        _putpixel32(bmp,xx,yy,Convert16BitToARGB(src[0]) & GetMaskBit(bitmask, xx, yy, w, h));
                        src++;
                        padding_checker += 2;
                        padding_checker &= 3;
                    }
                    //This loop jumps over any padding bytes.
                    while(padding_checker)
                    {
                        src = (uint16_t*)(((uint8_t*)src)+1);
                        padding_checker++;
                        padding_checker &= 3;
                    }
                }
                return bmp;
            }
            break;
            case 8:
            {
                if(colors > 256) colors = 256; //Color Count must be restricted to 256 entries at the most.
                if(colors <=  0) colors = 256; //Color Count might be reported as zero. This means 256.
                uint8_t* src = (((uint8_t*)data) + ignore_size + (colors << 2));
                uint32_t* pal = ((uint32_t*)(((uint8_t*)data) + ignore_size));
                uint8_t* bitmask = (uint8_t*)(((uint8_t*)data) + ignore_size + (colors << 2) + color_data_size);
                int padding_checker = 0;
                for(int yy = h-1; yy >= 0; --yy){
                    for(int xx = 0; xx < w; ++xx){
                        uint8_t color = src[0];
                        if(color < colors){
                            _putpixel32(bmp,xx,yy,(pal[color] | 0xFF000000) & GetMaskBit(bitmask, xx, yy, w, h));
                        }else{
                            _putpixel32(bmp,xx,yy,0x00FF00FF);
                        }
                        src++;
                        padding_checker++;
                        padding_checker &= 3;
                    }
                    //This loop jumps over any padding bytes.
                    while(padding_checker)
                    {
                        src++;
                        padding_checker++;
                        padding_checker &= 3;
                    }
                }
                return bmp;
            }
            break;
            case 4:
            {
                if(colors > 16) colors = 16; //Color Count must be restricted to 16 entries at the most.
                if(colors <= 0) colors = 16; //Color Count might be reported as zero. This means 16.
                uint8_t* src = (((uint8_t*)data) + ignore_size + (colors << 2));
                uint32_t* pal = ((uint32_t*)(((uint8_t*)data) + ignore_size));
                uint8_t* bitmask = (uint8_t*)(((uint8_t*)data) + ignore_size + (colors << 2) + color_data_size);
                int padding_checker = 0;
                for(int yy = h-1; yy >= 0; --yy){
                    for(int xx = 0; xx < w; ++xx){
                        uint8_t color = src[0];
                        if(xx & 1) color = ( color       & 0x0F);
                        else       color = ((color >> 4) & 0x0F);
                        if(color < colors){
                            _putpixel32(bmp,xx,yy,(pal[color] | 0xFF000000) & GetMaskBit(bitmask, xx, yy, w, h));
                        }else{
                            _putpixel32(bmp,xx,yy,0x00FF00FF);
                        }
                        if(xx & 1)
                        {
                            src++;
                            padding_checker++;
                            padding_checker &= 3;
                        }
                    }
                    //if the pointer hasn't incremented to the next byte yet, do so.
                    if(w & 1) //odd width
                    {
                        src++;
                        padding_checker++;
                        padding_checker &= 3;
                    }
                    //This loop jumps over any padding bytes.
                    while(padding_checker)
                    {
                        src++;
                        padding_checker++;
                        padding_checker &= 3;
                    }
                }
                return bmp;
            }
            break;
            case 1:
            {
                if(colors >  2) colors = 2; //Color Count must be restricted to 2 entries at the most.
                if(colors <= 0) colors = 2; //Color Count might be reported as zero. This means 2.
                uint32_t* pal        = (uint32_t*)(((uint8_t*)data) + ignore_size);
                uint8_t* bitmaskXOR = (uint8_t*)(((uint8_t*)data) + ignore_size + (colors << 2));
                uint8_t* bitmaskAND = (uint8_t*)(((uint8_t*)data) + ignore_size + (colors << 2) + color_data_size);
                uint32_t  ret_colors[4] = {pal[0]|0xFF000000, 0x00FF00FF, pal[1]|0xFF000000, 0x0000FF00};
                for(int yy = h-1; yy >= 0; --yy){
                    for(int xx = 0; xx < w; ++xx){
                        _putpixel32(bmp,xx,yy,GetColorMonochrome(bitmaskXOR, bitmaskAND, xx, yy, w, h, ret_colors));
                    }
                }
                return bmp;
            }
            break;
        }
        return bmp;
    }
}



vector< BITMAP* > ResourceToBitmapVector(HMODULE hm, HRSRC hr, bool is_group_icon)
{
    vector< BITMAP* > results;
    if(is_group_icon)
    {
        HGLOBAL hg = LoadResource(hm,hr);
        GRPICONDIR* gd = (GRPICONDIR*)LockResource(hg);
        if(gd->idType == 1)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < gd->idCount; ++i)
            {
                //WARNING: The GRPICONDIRENTRY's data might be wrong!
                GRPICONDIRENTRY* ie = (GRPICONDIRENTRY*)&(gd->idEntries[i]);
                HRSRC ihr = FindResource(hm,MAKEINTRESOURCE(ie->nID),RT_ICON);
                if(ihr != NULL)
                {
                    HGLOBAL ihg = LoadResource(hm,ihr);
                    void* data = (void*)LockResource(ihg);
                    DWORD size = SizeofResource(hm,ihr);
                    uint32_t b = ((BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(data))->biBitCount;
                    uint32_t w = ((BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(data))->biWidth;
                    uint32_t h = (((BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(data))->biHeight >> 1); //icons have doubled height value.
                    uint32_t c = ((BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(data))->biClrUsed;
                    results.push_back(CreateBmp32bppFromIconResData(data, size, b, w, h, c));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        HGLOBAL ihg = LoadResource(hm,hr);
        void* data = (void*)LockResource(ihg);
        DWORD size = SizeofResource(hm,hr);
        uint32_t b = ((BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(data))->biBitCount;
        uint32_t w = ((BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(data))->biWidth;
        uint32_t h = (((BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(data))->biHeight >> 1); //icons have doubled height value.
        uint32_t c = ((BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(data))->biClrUsed;
        results.push_back(CreateBmp32bppFromIconResData(data, size, b, w, h, c));
    }
    return results;
}



vector< BITMAP* > IconFileToBitmapVector(void* icon_data, uint32_t icon_size)
{
    vector< BITMAP* > results;
    ICONDIR* gd = (ICONDIR*)icon_data;
    if(gd->idType == 1) 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < gd->idCount; ++i)
        {
            //WARNING: The ICONDIRENTRY's data might be wrong!
            DWORD offset = gd->idEntries[i].dwImageOffset;
            DWORD size = gd->idEntries[i].dwBytesInRes;
            void* data = (void*)(((uint8_t*)icon_data) + ((uint32_t)offset));
            uint32_t b = ((BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(data))->biBitCount;
            uint32_t w = ((BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(data))->biWidth;
            uint32_t h = (((BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(data))->biHeight >> 1); //icons have doubled height value.
            uint32_t c = ((BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(data))->biClrUsed;
            results.push_back(CreateBmp32bppFromIconResData(data, size, b, w, h, c));
        }
    }
    return results;
}



vector< BITMAP* > UnearthIconResource(string& file, bool self_refrence, bool res_index, int index)
{
    #define LOAD_IGNORE_CODE_AUTHZ_LEVEL 0x00000010

    //prevents a negative indexing error 
    // (the boolean res_index handles whether it's icon index VS resource ID)
    index = abs(index); 

    vector< BITMAP* > results; //array of results to return (pointers to 32bpp images)

    //extract and 'demangle' the file extension by convertng to lowercase.
    string ext = get_file_extension(file.c_str());
    for(int i = 0; i < ext.size(); ++i) ext[i] = tolower(ext[i]);

    bool is_icl = false;
    if((ext == "exe") || (ext == "dll") || (ext == "scr") || (is_icl = (ext == "icl")))
    {
        // Portable Executable Resource (works for both DLL and EXE)
        // Also works for any 32bit Icon Library (Microangelo Studio?)
        HMODULE hm = LoadLibraryEx(file.c_str(), NULL, 
            (DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES | LOAD_IGNORE_CODE_AUTHZ_LEVEL | LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE));
        if(hm != NULL)
        {
            HRSRC hr;
            if(!self_refrence)
            {
                if(res_index)
                {
                    //The icon we want is at the resource ID (==index)
                    bool is_single_icon = false;
                    hr = FindResource(hm,MAKEINTRESOURCE(index),RT_GROUP_ICON);
                    if(hr == NULL)
                    {
                        hr = FindResource(hm,MAKEINTRESOURCE(index),RT_ICON);
                        is_single_icon = (hr != NULL);
                    }
                    if(hr != NULL)
                    {
                        results = ResourceToBitmapVector(hm, hr, !is_single_icon);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //The icon we want is the (index)'th icon in the file
                    //We must preform a manual search for the resource ID!
                    //WARNING: Using EnumResourceNames() *DOES NOT WORK PROPERLY* for this.
                    for(int nicon = 0, i = 0; i < 0x8000; ++i)
                    {
                        bool is_single_icon = false;
                        hr = FindResource(hm,MAKEINTRESOURCE(i),RT_GROUP_ICON);
                        if(hr != NULL)
                        {
                            if(nicon == index)
                            {
                                results = ResourceToBitmapVector(hm, hr, true);
                                break;
                            }
                            nicon++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //The icon we want is the "first" icon in the file. 
                //Happens when location is a %1.
                //We must preform a manual search for the resource ID!
                //WARNING: Using EnumResourceNames() *DOES NOT WORK PROPERLY* for this.
                for(int i = 0; i < 0x8000; ++i)
                {
                    bool is_single_icon = false;
                    hr = FindResource(hm,MAKEINTRESOURCE(i),RT_GROUP_ICON);
                    if(hr != NULL)
                    {
                        results = ResourceToBitmapVector(hm, hr, true);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            FreeLibrary(hm);
        }
        else /*if(is_icl)
        {//OH NOES. We have to load a *16bit* .icl file!
            //not supported yet. sorry. left as another excecise to the programmer.
        }*/
    }
    else if(ext == "ico")
    {
        //Single Icon File

        //###################################################
        //#  PSEUDO-CODE: Do the file loading yourself ;)
        void* data_pointer = NULL;
        uint32_t data_size = 0;
        if(data_pointer = MyLoadFile(file.c_str(), &data_size))
        {
            if(data_size)
            {
                results = IconFileToBitmapVector((void*)data_pointer, data_size);
            }
        }
        MyCloseFile(data_pointer);
    }
    return results;
}
```

I think that almost covers it all...

*One last thing I should mention:* Be sure to ignore the size and bit depth information coming from the icon directory entries. They can often be wrong. I've seen a few 256-color images reported as 24bit, causing data corruption inside the image loader.

Answer (score 1):

With all due respect, I'm afraid that the accepted solution is somewhat inefficient and contains several inaccuracies.

Here's a quick run-down:

1. Why parse the registry manually? You state the API has some problems. Like what? I've used registry parsing API extensively and never had a problem myself. Your Indexing vs ResID logic is correct though.
2. Why do the icon-to-bitmap conversions manually? This can be achieved with 3 to 5 lines of code using the right Icon API calls. [Here's a complete reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646973%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
3. Why limit the conversion to 32bpp? Again, using the right APIs will generate a device dependent hIcon handle with the max color bit-depth supported by that device. Check out the `CreateIconFromResourceEx()` API function. All you need to do is combine it with the `Find/Load/Lock Resource` APIs that you're already using. Using this technique will load icons of any size and color depth (from monochrome up to alpha-channel 32bpp icons).
4. Finally, regarding the search for icon resources by group (`RT_GROUP_ICON`), or by single icons (`RT_ICON`), and matching for a given index instead of resource, it could be done much more efficiently using `EnumResourceNames()`. It might be that you've failed to account for string resource identifiers when parsing the Enum return, because it seems you've omitted such case in your "manual" search-and-match procedure. This might be the source of your problems with `EnumResourceNames()`. It works perfectly fine for me. At the very least, the "manual" search should match up to 0xFFFF rather than 0x8000. [Res IDs are recommended in the 0x0001 to 0x8000 range, but legal in the 0x0000 to 0xFFFF range](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Resource_Script_Reference#Identifiers).

Comment: The code is actually _very_ fast, despite its bloat. Coupled with a very complex image rating/resize algorithm, this still gets 60+ icon sets (16, 32, and 48) per second. I'm happy with it :)

#1: See my comments below the question in reply to Raymond.
#2: The APIs only give me 16x16 and 32x32. I want the _raw image data_. I can't extract any other sizes using the APIs, nor can I access the PNG icons from an XP system.
#3: I work with Allegro extensively; the best way to process high color pixels in RAM memory is to use 32bit (using device _independent_ buffers, of course).

Comment: ...and regarding #4, I think I tried that at one point, but got faulty results. That's what led me to the manual search approach, which was the first thing I coded that actually worked correctly. I'll take note of the ID search range error. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You're only getting 16x16 and 32x32 icons because you're using the "wrong" flags for the APIs. Study the API further and you'll see that some flags cause it to return system SMALL and LARGE size icons, while the right combination of flags and the cx, cy parameters returns the actual resource size. Works perfectly fine for me. PNG icons are not supported on XP, but work fine with Vista+. As a side note, I've never seen PNG icons with resolutions smaller than 256x256. Finally, for all practical purposes, the APIs will yield a 32-bit icon unless you're working on 15 years or older devices.

Comment: Regarding resource ID enumeration, please note that your method is flawed not only due to range, but because it fails to check for string named resource IDs (as opposed to ordinal ID names). Low efficiency aside, your method doesn't work as supposed. If a library has an icon group resource named "AAA" and another named 1 for example, your method will load the 1 icon at index 0, and none other, when in fact, the enumeration should load the "AAA" icon as index 0, and then the 1 icon as index 1. This is why you need to use the `EnumResourceNames()` API. Recheck your code, the Enum API works fine.

Comment: `FindResource`->`LoadResource`->`LockResource`->`CreateIconFromResourceEx` will load from any size and depth to any size (original size if u want). Check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997538.aspx) and [this link](http://read.pudn.com/downloads12/sourcecode/windows/49707/ICONPRO/ICONS.C__.htm).

Comment: OK then. I'll have a look at `EnumResourceNames` and try coding it with that.
As for `CreateIconFromResourceEx` - it can return actual size, but... `"If the resource contains multiple images, the function uses the size of the first image"` ...and most icons contain _multiple_ images. What I'm actually doing is reading the dimensions/depth of _all images_ in the icon group, picking the best looking and/or closest image to each size that I want to extract (using a heuristic), ending with a special image resize on the picked icons. The results **aren't** the same as what gets chosen by Windows.

Comment: You're not understanding the usage of the CreateIcon API. To load a specific icon part of an icon group, you find/load/lock resource twice, first time for the icon group through a RT_GROUP_ICON enumeration, and then search&match the returned array for a specific icon resource ID which u again find/load/lock and pass its handle to the CreateIcon API. I've posted several links detailing this. Check my previous posts. The results aren't the same for you because you're demanding an automatic icon from an icon group rather than traversing its array and loading a specific "sub icon" as needed.

Comment: Ah, so that's what I was doing wrong!! I think that clears everything up. Thanks for being persistent :)

Answer (score 0):

If it does have not to be platform independent:

a bit time ago i wrote a little class that reads a file and extract all icons.
It retreives a std::vector with HICONs.
With GetIconInfo you can retreive the HBITMAP for pixeldata an pixelmask.

The function is a little bit heuristic. It scans the binary Data for a typical icon begin and tries to load them.
The function also works on dlls, exe or icl (16bit dlls that just contain icon resources)

```
#ifndef __ICON_LIST_H__
#define __ICON_LIST_H__

#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>



class IconFile: public std::vector<HICON>{
public:

  IconFile(){};

  IconFile(std::string i_filename){
    addIconsFromFile(i_filename);
  };

  int addIconsFromFile(std::string i_fileName){
    int iCount=0;
    HANDLE file = CreateFile( i_fileName.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if(file!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
      int   size   = GetFileSize(file,NULL);
      DWORD actRead;
      BYTE* buffer = new BYTE[size];
      ReadFile(file, buffer, size, &actRead, NULL);
      CloseHandle(file);
      int ind = -1;
      for(int p = 0; p< size-4; ++p){
        if(buffer[p]==40 && buffer[p+1]==0 && buffer[p+2]==0 && buffer[p+3]==0){
          HICON icon = CreateIconFromResourceEx(&buffer[p], size-p, true, 0x00030000,0,0,0);
          if(icon){
            ++iCount;
            this->push_back(icon);
          }
        }
      }     
      delete[] buffer;
    }
    return iCount;
  };

};


#endif //__ICON_LIST_H__
```