# SHGetImageList returns an icon that is too small for the size

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to retrieve file icons on Windows. I follow this guide http://pogopixels.com/blog/getting-the-48x48-or-256x256-icon-of-a-file-on-windows/

I use SHIL_JUMBO to get the maximum size possible. However, not all icons returned are big enough, such as the QuickTime icon in the attached image. The size of the whole pixmap returned is still 256x256 but it does not fill the entire space. My program will then scale it down, making it too tiny to see.

I'm wondering if I can retrieve some extra info such as the size of the original icon, so I know that it's too small to scale down.

[image: The Icon is too small for the size]

Comment: There is one comment under the answer which is exactly what I'm asking.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839588/extract-high-resolution-icon-or-thumbnail-for-file?rq=1

Comment: Hi, i didn't see any comment answering to that problem. Do you know how to determine if icon must be loaded in jumbo or not ?